# Failed to load a library with logtalk_load using logtalk 3.0.0.1

Tags: swi-prolog, logtalk

I use `SWI Prolog` as a backed compiler(v 6.6.1). After installing `logtalk` 3.0.0.1 I started getting error when

> logtalk_load(library(types_loader), [source_data(on), report(on)]).
>
> % [ c:/users/dizqj373/documents/logtalk/library/termp.lgt loaded ]
> !     Domain error: value alias/2 is not in domain directive
> !       in directive :- alias(termp,[variables/2 as vars/2])
> !       in file c:/users/dizqj373/documents/logtalk/library/term.lgt between lines 36-37
> Warning: [Thread 2] c:/users/dizqj373/documents/logtalk/library/lgt_tmp/types_loader.pl:5: Initialization goal failed
> % [ c:/users/dizqj373/documents/logtalk/library/types_loader.lgt loaded ]
> true.

Could you help me and guide a little bit what could be wrong?
thanks!

Comment: fixed! The MVS used the old $LOGTALKHOME value.

Answer (score 0):

The `alias/2` directive was introduced in Logtalk 3, deprecating the less readable `alias/3` directive used in Logtalk 2.x. The error you posted would be expected if you try to compile and load the Logtalk 3 library using the Logtalk 2.x compiler, which would not recognize the new `alias/2` directive.

If you have just updated from Logtalk 2.x to Logtalk 3, make sure you're indeed using the new version compiler. Check that the current value of the `LOGTALKHOME` environment variable points to the Logtalk 3 installation folder and not to an old Logtalk 2.x folder. After starting Logtalk, you can also check the version that you're using with the query:

```
| ?- current_logtalk_flag(version_data, Version).
```

This flag was also introduced in Logtalk 3. If you can an error that the flag is not recognized, then you most likely are loading the old Logtalk 2.x version.